# Can't display values instead of labels in dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I am trying to display my values in my dropdown list but it shows me the labels. As you can see from the data it's designed as {label, value}. Everything looks normal I couldn't find the problem. I hope some of you can help.

If you want to check the Dropdown library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown

This is my data which comes with **setDropdown(item.options):**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "label": "319",
    "value": "Ahşap",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "320",
    "value": "Betonarme",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "321",
    "value": "Çelik ",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "322",
    "value": "Kütük",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "323",
    "value": "Prefabrik",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "label": "332",
    "value": "Var",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "333",
    "value": "Yok",
  },
]... and goes on
```

**App.js**

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

        //it will arrange object(object) => array(object)
  function setDropdown(query) {
    const response = query;
    try {
      const array = Object.entries(response).map(([key, value]) => ({
        label: key,
        value: value,
      }));
      return array;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

function renderItems({ item }) {
let dropdownData = setDropdown(item.options);
    if (Object.keys(item.options).length > 0) {
      //console.log(item.name + " is dropdown");
      //console.log(dropdownData); I shared the data at the beginning of the post
      return (
        <View>
          <CustomDropdown
            text={item.name}
            data={dropdownData}
            value={selected}
            setValue={setSelected}
          />
        </View>
      );
    } else if (Object.keys(item.options).length == 0) {
      const keyboardType = item.numeric ? "numeric" : "default";
      //console.log(item.name + " is textinput");
      return (
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={item.name}
            keyboardType={keyboardType}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

**CustomDropdown.js**

```
function CustomDropdown({ text, data, value, setValue }) {
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", padding: 10, borderRadius: 15 }}>
        <Dropdown
          style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: "blue" }]}
          placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
          selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
          inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
          placeholder={!isFocus ? text : "..."}
          data={data}
          maxHeight={300}
          labelField="label"
          valueField="value"
          onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
          value={value}
          onChange={(item) => {
            setValue(item.value);
            setIsFocus(false);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where does your Dropdown component come from?

Comment: It's a library by itself which is "react-native-element-dropdown". Which means it's the root component

Comment: Can you check the result of setDropdown(item.options) again? Maybe its default value should be like this: [
    { label: 'Item 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Item 2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Item 3', value: '3' },
    { label: 'Item 4', value: '4' },
    { label: 'Item 5', value: '5' },
    { label: 'Item 6', value: '6' },
    { label: 'Item 7', value: '7' },
    { label: 'Item 8', value: '8' },
  ]

Comment: I did it but still the same.

Comment: Please test with a static value instead of setDropdown(item.options). for example, data={[
    { key: 'Item 1', value: 'value 1' },
    { key: 'Item 2', value: 'value 2' },
  ]}

Comment: Please share codesandbox link with your example.

Comment: I can get the data without problem, I don't think that it needs to be static. I also assign it as dropdownData = setDropdown(item.options) and changed the filedvalues. Looks like working for now but if you have better solution. Please share with me. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add label prop in your data objects. It probably looks for one and as it doesn't find it takes the value of the first prop in the object. You can do this by changing your data structure or mapping the data array when you pass it to the Dropdown like this:

```
data.map(option => {
  return {
    ...option,
    label: option.value
  }
})
```

Comment: "Key" is the label in my data. I changed it to label, still the same

Comment: Sorry for late respond I understand what you mean now. You were right from the beginning. Value needs to be first prop of the object. I changed it as "label: value"

Answer (score 1):

`onChange={(item) => { setValue(item.value); setIsFocus(false); }}`
you should `setValue(item)`

and then

`<Dropdown value = {value}/>`  where value is `{label:string,value:YourType}` object

not just value.value

hope you get me